# RESTful API with Google API and OAuth2

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

As the title says, I want to create a RESTful API (stateless) that will access Google API endpoints. First I want to authenticate the user and then use that token provided by Google to access Google Calendar API.

This is the current flow of the app:

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xzbd.png)

Is there any other way to achieve this since my Nodejs service is signing an already signed JWT token provided by Google (I need to track expiration times for both access tokens)?

I am doing this because I don't want to use Google's access token for my own endpoint authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valid `embedded token` pattern, where  the Google access token is just a `custom claim` in your own access token.

- The client can call your API, using its main token
- The API can authorize correctly, based on claims and scopes you have issued for your own data
- When required, your API can use the embedded token to get external Google data the user has consented to

Your API should handle 401s from Google APIs in the standard way, as in [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/apiClient.ts#L41).

Your nodejs service is actually implementing 2 roles here. Consider separating these into a `token service` and a `business service`:

- Token issuing. A technical job most commonly done by an authorization server.
- REST API. A business focused component.

Comment: Thank you for your validation and the given example! I also wondered how to handle both access tokens' expiry times, but your example seems to clarify that.